# ¿Cómo puedo crear accesos directos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un pequeño problema, lo que sucede es que quiero crear accesos directos a mis formularios hijos pulsando una sola tecla lo estoy creando con el evento KeyDown pero veo que al presionar la tecla solo lo ejecuta una vez y cuando cierro la ventana y y quiero volverla a abrir con la tecla ya no abre

```
private void frm_Menu_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
        {
            if (formAlmacen == null)
            {
                formAlmacen = new frm_Almacen();
                formAlmacen.Show();
                formAlmacen.MdiParent = this;
                formAlmacen.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(CerrarFormulario);
                lbl_mensaje.Text = "Bienvenido al Almacen";
                lbl_nombre.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                formAlmacen.Activate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! creo que java no tiene nada que ver con c#... tampoco parece tener que ver con tu problema Entity-framework.. al menos yo no veo ninguna base de datos ahi...

Comment: de paso.. cambiaste de form, cambio el foco.. tu form ya no esta recibiendo las teclas...

Comment: Que es lo que hay en tu primer formulario, da mas detalles

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.